# Adding new column to ag-grid column groups

Tags: ag-grid

I have created a table using ag-grid angular. In that i have two column groups. 
I want to add a new column in first group and the new column should be in second place in the group.

But when i added the new column group, it placed at the end of all columns.

How can i bring that new column to required place.

Comment: Please share some code for how you are adding the new column group.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of the columns by using **moveColumn(colKey, toIndex)** in the columnApi:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/

```
> moveColumn(colKey, toIndex)
```

> Moves a column to toIndex. The column is first removed, then added at
>   the toIndex location, thus index locations will change to the right of
>   the column after the removal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use property `applyColumnDefOrder: true` in your grid options

https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/column-updating-definitions/#applying-column-order

> When Column Definitions are provided for existing Columns, the order
> of the Columns inside the grid is not changed to match the order of
> the newly provided Column Definitions. This is by design so that any
> reordering of the columns a user does to the grid is not lost when the
> Column Definitions get updated.
>
> If the desired behaviour is that Columns should be ordered to match
> the new set of Column Definitions, set the grid property
> `applyColumnDefOrder=true`.